# How to fix EditText with inputType 'DATE' don't show / in keyboard android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an EditText with inputType of 'date', in the emulator I see this:

[image]

But in my phone (GalaxyS8) I see this:

[image]

So I cannot set a date because I haven't character **/**. How can I fix that?

**Edit:** Samsung doesn't add / automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My answer just had been deleted.. Here is the solution :

Based on [this post](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/682), Samsung seems to have implemented automatic separator.

Did you try to tap some numbers? It normally will show some separator after few numbers

Comment: It looks to be a bug, try implementing a datepicker instead, it works fine and it's better for the users to select a date from a calendar than entering it by hand

Comment: Changed to DatePicker :) Thanks!